# How to change one URL to another with JQuery

Tags: jquery, safari-extension

I have the following script:

```
<script>  
safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);  

function performCommand(event) {    
    if (event.command == "change") {  


    $('a[href="http://example.com"]').attr('href', 'http://sub.example.com');


    }  
}  
</script>
```

And what I want to happen is that when the menu bar button is pressed, it runs the code in between (in this case, `('a[href="http://example.com"]').attr('href', 'http://sub.example.com');`) which finds all links and replaces them with the modified version. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you also explain some symptoms of your problem? What seems to wrong/invalid/not working at all?

Comment: Well, when I use this as a safari extension, it calls the script but it doesn't call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to change your selector so it only finds links that begin with the domain you'd like. This can be accomplished using ^=`instead of just`=`:

```
$('a[href^="http://example.com"]').attr('href',function(i,e){
  // we use a function so we can modify it instead of overwrtie
  return e.replace('example.com','google.com');
});
```

Comment: Well I only want to replace the http://example with http://sub.example. I mistyped in the main post.

Comment: so modify the `.replace` to be: `.replace('//example.com'.'//sub.example.com')`

Comment: Ok, I did that but the script still isn't running the function when the menubar button is pressed.

Comment: I assume you're on a mac given safari and the "command" binding, so fixing your link replace is as far as I can take you, sorry. ;-\